# Typecsript override readonly property getter implementation from external library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm new to Typescript and Angular. I'm in situation where I need to override property of the Material Design Library version: `2.0.0-beta.12`. I need to override this readonly public property:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.12/src/lib/chips/chip-list.ts#L242

I noticed that they have a bug and implementation should be:

```
get shouldPlaceholderFloat(): boolean {
    return !this.empty;
}
```

So I wanted to correct this without waiting for the creators of this library to fix this. How to replace the body/implementation of this property getter. I need to make this fast. Is there any way that I can override this in Typescript in Angular project that is using this Material Design UI Library. In general I would ask how to add/change properties/methods in other classes that are imported and we directly not control them. What is the best approach? This is my `ng -v` output:

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.3
Node: 6.11.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/cli: 1.5.3
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.21
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.37
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.7
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Comment: Why don't you just update your dependencies? They may have fixed it.

Comment: Because next version is for Angular 5 and I don't want to rewrite whole project because of it.